# When is it safe to not synchronize read/write variables?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

In Java, when can one "get away" with not using synchronized on variables that are read/write for multiple concurrent threads?

I read about a couple of surprising concurrency bugs: [double-checked-locking](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) and [hash-maps](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html), and have always used synchronize by default in shared read/write cases, however, I started to wonder when it's OK to not.

For example, what sort of general rules can I use to decide when it's *actually* safe to omit `synchronized` from methods like this:

```
T getFoo() {
  if (this.foo == null) {
    this.foo = createFoo() // createFoo is always thread safe.
  }
  return this.foo;
}
```

Where:

- `T` might be primitives or arbitrary objects
- `createFoo` is always thread-safe and can be called multiple times, but is otherwise unspecified.
- `getFoo()` can be "eventually consistent".

Is it OK if T are primitives like `int`? What about `Integer`? What about simple objects, like String? Etc.

Comment: It's never okay not to, unless you can somehow semantically guarantee that you won't be reading and writing at the same time (or if you don't care if some of your workers are reading the wrong thing after it's been updated)

Comment: Only if you know at any point of time there will be only one thread to access it.

Comment: *There is **no guarantee** that the value will be seen by **any** thread after it is updated* without the appropriate synchronization (`synchronized` is a common, but not the only method). Thread-safety is more than just interleaved instructions/schedules.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: yes, i don't care if different workers get different instances. For example, if T was "Integer" and createFoo() just returned new Integer(42). The "eventually consistency" behavior is OK

Comment: If eventual consistency is fine with you then I suppose there would be no need for synchronization. Make 100% sure you're fine with that though haha

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner Except there is *no guarantee* of 'eventual consistency' without further context; while one could go down the `volatile` route, I feel like this question is missing the important context .. eventually consistent or not.

Comment: @user2864740 what further context can I provide? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @RichardLevasseur Code. For example, if the field is not `volatile` then there is *no guarantee* of any 'eventual consistency'. Reading through the JVM specification on 'happens-before' relationships would probably be enlightening: if it is not guaranteed, then it is not guaranteed.

Comment: I updated the question to include that its ok if getFoo is eventually consistent

Comment: @user2864740 so is that to say: if its not volatile, then `this.foo` is _sort of_ like being a thread-local variable?

Comment: @RichardLevasseur No, absolutely not. Rather, there is *no guarantee* (note how I keep emphasising that?) when other threads will see any updates to the field - it could be immediately; or never. That is, changes to the variable [may not be *memory-visible* to other threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#Multithreaded_programming_and_memory_visibility). `volatile` adds an additional guarantee, as discussed in the [JLS happens-before relationships](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html).

Comment: It is ok if you *know* what you are doing. For example look at java.lang.String hash field, used for hashcode cashing. It is computed if not visible - so you might end up computing it from multiple threads, but in normal case you will need to do it only once. No point in wasting memory barrier on each single access to save some cpu in 0.00001% case of not seeing value immediately in other thread.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski ..or visible at all. Strings and the internal hash field have additional restrictions that make such easier to reason about: the source of the function is immutable; and the result of the function is immutable and identity-free.

Comment: concurrently mutating `HashMap` leading to serious corruption should not be surprising at all. http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/ may be a good read for the specific case of object initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When is it safe to not synchronize read/write variables?**

The tongue-in-cheek answer is *Only when you fully understand the implications to the underlying hardware, the JVM, and your application*. If possible, I'd still recommend this approach, which begins with a lot of reading and experiments.

In practice, you should be able to use some commonly used patterns to minimize the amount of `synchronized` methods or blocks in your code, without understanding all the intricacies of said patterns. That shouldn't increase the risk for your application too much, because there are non-trivial details even around the usage of `synchronized`, and if you understood all of these details, you would have asked a different question.

Still, your mileage may vary, especially if the form and implementation of said commonly used patterns is not blessed by your local concurrency guru.

**Enough blabbering, give me some examples**

1. Using thread-safe collections, utilities, and types.

   - This includes relying on `java.util.concurrent` where possible.
   - There's also a wonderful amount of additional libraries and tools for Java outside of the JDK and its ecosystem, but they do not qualify as easily for "apply now, read more later".
2. Using `volatile`

   - You can take a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp06197/ for some common patterns using `volatile` variables.
3. Using safe initialization and safe publication

   - You can take a look at http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/ for what can be a slightly more advanced explanation than is appropriate for a beginner.
   - I'd also put using immutable types here.
4. Keeping data thread-local.

   - Kind of a no-brainer, and surprisingly often applicable.

Comment: Great answer. I maintain several Task/Data open-source parallel services and leave the statistics variables as simple int or long without volatile or locking. However, I have explicit comments how to "protect" these variables should the need arise.

Answer (score 1):

It's never safe to share data between threads without a memory barrier.

The correctness of your `getFoo()` depends on the declaration of the `foo` field.

If `getFoo()` is called by multiple threads, every thread might end up with a different instance of `T`. Without a memory barrier, actions by one thread (like assignment to the field `foo`) might never become visible to other threads—ever! In other words, without synchronizaton, consistency, "eventual" or otherwise, is not guaranteed.

If `foo` is `volatile`, that serves as a sufficient memory barrier, and then you just have the problem that multiple threads might get a different `T` for a short period of time as they race to create instances.